# PhpStorm with common library folder

Tags: phpstorm

Here is how our server is set up:

```
/var/www/vhosts:

composer.json
library/
vendor/
website1/
website2/
website3...
```

We think of the whole server as one project. Today I only care about `website1` (and composer.json, library, vendor). But the base URL is going to be website1.com.

How do I set that up? Is my project root `/var/www/vhosts` or `/var/www/vhosts/website1`?

Comment: Setup where exactly? You can create new project using any of those folders as a project root. Then either exclude unwanted folders (in first case) or add additional Content Roots (and perhaps symlink for composer.json in 2nd). Some clarification with screenshot are welcome.

Comment: This sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3414 . You can also try to add another mapping in Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment > Mappings and specify a web path for a directory there. But opening website1 as a separate project would be the easiest way.